# implementing react-native-fbsdkshare

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native

I have followed the guide written on https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk to install and use the react-native-fbsdk module. However, when I click the "Share" button it throws the following error:

```
'Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating \'FBSDKShareDialogInterface.show\')
```

Also 3 warnings appear when I run the app:

'Warning: Native component for "RCTFBSDKShareButton" does not exist'
'Warning: Native component for "RCTFBSDKSendButton" does not exist'
'Warning: Native component for "RCTFBSDKLikeControl" does not exist'

This is the code that I use:

var FBSDKShare           = require('react-native-fbsdkshare');

var {
  FBSDKShareDialog,
  FBSDKShareDialogInterface,
  FBSDKShareLinkContent,
  FBSDKShareShareButton
} = FBSDKShare;

```
shareOnFacebook() {

      var linkContent = new FBSDKShareLinkContent('https://facebook.com', 'Wow, check out this great site!', 'Facebook.com', null);
// Share the link using the native share dialog.
FBSDKShareDialog.show(linkContent, (error, result) => {
  if (!error) {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      alert('Share cancelled.');
    } else {
      alert('Thanks for sharing!');
    }
  } else {
    alert('Error sharing.');
  }
});

<TouchableHighlight style={[itemStyles.itemButtonShare,itemStyles.itemButtonShareFacebook]} onPress={() => this.shareOnFacebook(item)}><Text>Share On Facebook</Text></TouchableHighlight>
```

(I have FBSDKCoreKit.framework, FBSDKLoginKit.framework and FBSDKShareKit.framework already installed and framework search path is set.)
Anyone can help with this error please?
thanks

*----- EDITED -------*

Ok finally I decided to create a native method and call it from react side. If anybody faces this problem this is the alternate solution:

Create 2 files, FacebookShareManager.h and FacebookShareManager.m :

The content of FacebookShareManager.h should be:

```
    #import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface FacebookShareManager : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

and the content of the FacebookShareManager.m :

```
    #import "FacebookShareManager.h"
#import "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h"
#import "FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h"

@implementation FacebookShareManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(showDialog: (NSDictionary *)params callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback ) {


  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];

    NSURL    *    shareUrl      = [NSURL URLWithString:params[@"contentUrl"]];
    NSURL    *    shareImageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:params[@"contentImageUrl"]];
    NSString * shareTitle       = [NSString stringWithString:params[@"contentTitle"]];
    NSString * shareDescription = [NSString stringWithString:params[@"contentDescription"]];

    content.contentURL         = shareUrl;
    content.imageURL           = shareImageUrl;
    content.contentTitle       = shareTitle;
    content.contentDescription = shareDescription;

    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:nil
                                 withContent:content
                                    delegate:nil];

  });

};

@end
```

Now you we need to call this method from our react-native component:

First include the manager at the top of your react-native component class file:

```
var FacebookShareManager = require('NativeModules').FacebookShareManager;
```

Now inside your component class add this method:

```
    shareOnFacebook(item) {


      var params = {"contentUrl": item.url,"contentImageUrl": item.pictureUrl,"contentTitle": item.title,"contentDescription":item.description};
      FacebookShareManager.showDialog(params, (info)=> {


        // do something you need...


    });

  }
```

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt the app in XCode and restarted the React Native Packager process since installing the component?

Comment: Yes I have restarted the packager several times. Rebuilt the project several times. Nothing changes @jevakallio

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to create a native method to call from react side:

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, and it turned out that I had facebook sdk v4.7.1.
So

1. I removed the previous and downloaded the latest v4.8.0.
2. Then I followed again all steps starting from installing [JavaScript packages](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#javascript-packages)
3. Then manually added [files to xcode](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#option-manually-add-files-to-xcode).

After I used share dialogs from example on github and everything works fine now.